# Button selects webpage (from list) based on date

Tags: javascript, datetime

I am terrible with Javascript but learning from my bruises.

On the site I am working on - I currently have a page setup for everyday of the year (i.e. January 1st has its own page '01-jan-01.html' January 2nd is '01-jan-02.html') - I want to make a button that will look up the current date then send the user to the corresponding page (Think 'This day in history').

I already have a button that will pick one of these pages at random and the code works see below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var urls = [
          '01-jan-01.html'
          '01-jan-02.html'
           ....
];

function goSomewhere() {
    var url = urls[Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length)];
    window.location = url; // redirect
}
```

Then on my button I simply call goSomewhere() on the onClick() and as i said earlier, this works fine. However I can't figure out how to select based on the CURRENT DATE. any help would be greatly appreciated. thank you!

EDIT: No answers but here is the progress so far:

```
<script>
var day = date.getDate();
var month = date.getMonth();
  function goSomewhere() {
    var url = month + "-" + day];
    window.location = url; // redirect
}
</script>
```

This wouldn't even solve my problem entirely but its how I'm trying to wrap my head around the logic. In the above code I would still need to find a way to incorporate the 'jan' (month) varible in each webpage link since the formatting is 'MM-mmmmm-DD' - would it be easier if I change the naming mechanic to simply "MM-DD"? I'd prefer not to since it would involve a lot of manual work. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; 
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var yy = yyyy.toString().substr(2,2); //get two digit year
if(dd<10){ dd='0'+dd } 
if(mm<10){ mm='0'+mm } 
location.href = yy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd+'.html';
```